# Required type removes knowledge of function type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to take an optional argument from some other type and make it required in my type. But I don't seem to get it to work. Could someone help me point out what I'm doing wrong here?

```js
type MyType = {
    func?: (value: number) => void;
    other: string;
};

type NewType = {
    func: Required<MyType['func']>;
}

function hello(): NewType {
    return {
        // value is unknown
        func: value => value * 2,
    };
}

// func should not be optional!
const value = hello().func(25);
```

See example here: [TypeScript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsmAKpWBeGBvYMcwGYCuAdgMYD8AXDABQBuAhgDYFRVEEC2ARlAE4CUMVAD4YtAPYBLACYBubLnEgAFnyoBnEL0lEA5vIC+80ChgA5KAHdk0IZgU5CpKgCUoARwKTeUaQB4EGygAbQByJxJQgF1hQ2BgCJBJcSIYVUZGcWp+KgtrUyxcGB8QAl5UwqLcCKoGZjRROpYYACoYACYAGgcYI2ADeOASFM0xJmb0dMzsgDoI6naAVn55IA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

Use [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) instead

```js
type MyType = {
    func?: (value: number) => void;
    other: string;
};

type NewType = {
    func: NonNullable<MyType['func']>;
}

function hello(): NewType {
    return {
        func: value => value * 2,
    };
}

const value = hello().func(25);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQVtQGYFcA7AYwH4AuKACgDcBDAG3wksPwFsAjCAJwEooyAHxQaAewCWAEwDcWHGOAALXpQDOwHhMIBzOQF85GUJCgA5CAHdEp1Jhx4ixSmbGEz+BgzqcGEADxwNhAA2gDkBCRhALpCBhgYkcTAEm5QKl5iVHwuVsHo8tg8EMD4PIQFDg5JlPRMKCJ1zFAAVFAATAA0hVCGGPoJxG4aoozNqBkMWXwAdElU7QCsfHJAA)

### Reason

Check this code - [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=69#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQVtQGYFcA7AYwH4AuKACgDcBDAG3wksPwFsAjCAJwEooyAHxQaAewCWAEwDcWHGOAALXpQDOwHhMIBzOQF85GUJCgANQbARIA2gHICJOwF0oAejfVajZqw7d+QRFxaQEAHygiKQhcbQgpPmMkKABVNW0dACUIAEd8CR54y2y8gviAHjMRDy96JhYoNi5eAWFRSQSoCKiYuKkk0zSMgDkxQmH8BgY6TgYUKFHxyenZiErqz296v2bAtpD+gegh3RL8wqkAQQZgYtzzio0tXS7IwmjYwniNqCeM156n3iR1S6V0iwmUxmc2ut1QEOW0LWfxe3XevS+Uh+KJ0QA)

```js
type MyType = {
    func?: (value: number) => void;
    other: string;
};

type X = MyType['func'] // ((value: number) => void) | undefined)
type UsingRequired = Required<X> // ((value: number) => void) | undefined
type UsingNonNullable = NonNullable<X> // (value: number) => void

type UsingRequiredAlt = Required<string | undefined> // string | undefined
type UsingNonNullableAlt = NonNullable<string | undefined> // string
```

The prop `func` is optional in `MyType` i.e. it may be `undefined` also. So type of `X` is `((value: number) => void) | undefined`

The `Required<TypePassed>` utility type makes ***props*** of `TypePassed` required (removes undefined from them) not the type `TypePassed` itself.

So the type of `UsingRequiredAlt` is `string | undefined`

On the other hand, `NonNullable<TypePassed>` removes `null`/`undefined` from the `TypePassed`

So the type of `UsingNonNullableAlt` is `string`.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it work by taking indexing on the result of `Required` rather than on `MyType`, i.e. `Required<MyType['func']>` ~> `Required<MyType>['func']`.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=11&pln=8&pc=35#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsmAKpWBeGBvYMcwGYCuAdgMYD8AXDABQBuAhgDYFRVEEC2ARlAE4CUMVAD4YtAPYBLACYBubLnEgAFnyoBnEL0lEA5vIC%2080ChgA5KAHdk0IZgU5CpKgCUoARwKTeUaQB4EGyhhAG0AcicSMIBdQ2BgSJBJcSIYVUZGcWp%20KgtrUyxcGB8QAl5UwqLcSKoGZjRROpYYACoYACYAGgcYI2ADeOASFM0xJmb0dMzsgDpI6naAVn55IA)

Answer (score 1):

`NewType` requires the optional `func` property from `MyType` to be present. A required optional property is still optional. To solve this you could specify the function itself as a type and reuse it in both `MyType` and `NewType`.

```
// MyFunc defines a reusable func type
type MyFunc = (value: number) => void;

type MyType = {
    // Optional
    func?: MyFunc;
    other: string;
};

type NewType = {
    // Required
    func: MyFunc;
}

function hello(): NewType {
    return {
        func: value => value * 2,
    };
}


const value = hello().func(25);
```